# C# is half to even (banking rounding) equivalent to MidpointRounding.ToEven?

Tags: c#

Recently I needed to implement **"half to even"** rounding method for an electronical documents.

I need to know if c# *MidpointRounding.ToEven* method of *Math.Rounding* function implements **Half to even** (Banking rounding) or if need to make it by myself .

Comment: You can always check the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0#system-midpointrounding-toeven

Comment: If you can't find it in docs then you can just create a small application and try. When you try with some of your inputs and analyze the results you will exactly know if `ToEven` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch Tks. Just thinking someone else dealed with it before me. I'm going to tests table.. tks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says exactly what you want:

> **ToEven**: The strategy of rounding to the nearest number, and when a number is halfway between two others, it's rounded toward the nearest even number.

And then you can try it (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mtly2u):

```
Math.Round(3.34, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.3
Math.Round(3.35, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.4
Math.Round(3.36, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.4
Math.Round(3.44, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.4
Math.Round(3.45, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.4
Math.Round(3.46, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ==> 3.5
```